# intransitive use of "drink"

Tags: objects, direct-objects

In the following sentence, the object **it** is necessary, isn't it? But why?

> a. The milk was so hot that I couldn't drink [it].

The verb **drink** has an intransitive use, not necessarily related to alcohol.

> The baby still drinks from a bottle.

> He opened the can and drank thirstily.

> She filled the glass and drank.

So why is the object necessary in (a)?

Comment: You're right - it totally sounds weird without the "it", even though it is perfectly clear from context what you couldn't drink. I'll be interested to see if anyone can explain this.

Comment: *The milk was so hot that I couldn't drink.* is valid, if you are trapped in a cabin in the woods where there is nothing to drink but that hot milk.

Answer (score 1):

Your example (a):

> The milk was so hot that I couldn't drink [it].

would be valid if phrased as:

> (a1) The milk was so hot that I couldn't drink.

However, either is really short for:

> (a1) The milk was so hot that I couldn't drink the milk.

When "drink" is used as an intransitive verb, the sentence does not explicitly indicate **what** is being drunk. Sometimes it is unclear or unknown, and he speaker may not care; sometimes it is implied.

Let's look at your examples:

> (b) The baby still drinks from a bottle.

Here the baby may be drinking milk, or water, or juice, or something else. We don't know, and the speaker doesn't care.

> (c) He opened the can and drank thirstily.

It may be soda or beer or something else. Previous context may have made this clear, but for the purposes of **this** sentence, we don't know or care.

> (d) She filled the glass and drank.

This is the same situation.

Now let's look at some other examples:

> The animals came down to the waterhole to drink.

Here it is clearly implies that the animals drank water, so any object would be redundant.

> (e) Mary takes great pleasure in eating and drinking.

Here any and every kind of beverage is meant, so no object is needed.

> (f) John has quit drinking.

Here the clear implication is "drinking alcoholic beverages" so an object would again be redundant.

> (g) I'll drink to that!

Here the meaning of "drink" is different, it means offer or join in  a  toast. Here the object is almost surely "an alcoholic beverage", and neither speaker nor reader cares which one, particularly if the drinking is only metaphorical. Indeed "drink to" could be thought of as a phrasal verb related to but not the same as "drink".

The above examples are largely taken from or modified from these two dictionary definitions:

- [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/drink)
- [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drink)

Similar examples could easily be found in other dictionaries or elsewhere.

### Conclusion

It would seem that a good rule of thumb (not an absolute rule) is that the verb "drink" may be used without an object when either any plausible liquid is meant, or other contest has already made it clear what liquid is meant, so an explicit object would be redundant

As I wrote above, I think (a1) with the final "it" is perfectly acceptable, and it does not sound "weird" to me. However, I am confident that the form with "it" is much more common. Why?  I am, not sure. Perhaps because the implied object "milk" is separated from the verb by an number of words, and is in a different clause. Perhaps because milk is less likely to be hot than coffee, tea, or soup.

> (h)  The tea was so hot that I couldn't drink.

The sentence (h) seems more plausible to me than (a1) does, but even here an "it" would often be added. I cant specify any wider principle that explains this.

In a comment, user Maciej Stachowski suggests that the ending of (a1) "...that I couldn't drink." can easily be read to mean "I was unable to drink anything at all.  Indeed I can imagine a context in which (a1) took this sense. For example:

> (i) I gulped the heated milk. It seared my throat. I tried to ease it with some cold water but i couldn't. The milk was so hot that I couldn't drink.

So this would suggest that the use of the "it" is preferred, that (a) is preferred to (a1), because it avoids the ambiguity demonstrated by (i). This is in line with my rule of thumb because it means that here the listener **does** care what liquid is meant.

Or, as Maciej Stachowski put it, (a1) is a valid sentence with a completely different meaning, nd the "it" in (a) is needed to rule this out.

Comment: I don't think this explanation works.  The way I read (c) and (d), it is perfectly clear without any further context that the specifically referenced beverage in the can / bottle is what is being drunk.  Yet "it" is not required.  In the case of (a), I think that context makes the thing being drunk - milk - very clear as well, yet omitting the "it" would sound strange.

Comment: @cruthers
 I have edited to address this, but i don't fully agree that omitting the "it" from (a) sounds strange. I could imagine myself saying or writing (a) without the "it"

Comment: I find (a) to be perfectly valid grammatically, but making no sense semantically - the milk being hot does not prevent you from drinking *in general*, it prevents you from drinking *that milk* specifically. Cf. *My teeth hurt so bad that I couldn't drink* - which makes much more sense. (In other words - the *it* is required because omitting *it* results in a perfectly valid sentence with a different meaning)

Comment: @MaciejStachowski Are you a native speaker of English?

Comment: @Apollyon No, I'm ESL.

Comment: @Maciej Stachowski  Intersting. Certainly "*...that I couldn't drink.*" could be read as meaning "...that I was unable to drink anything  at all.  This again fits my general rule, here an object is needed to avoid ambiguity. I will add that to my answer.

Comment: @Maciej Stachowski  I have edited the answer to refer to your suggestion.

Comment: Maciej Stachowski doesn't say (a1) is ambiguous; rather, he says it's semantically odd.

Comment: @Apollyon I have edited to more closely track what 
Maciej Stachowski actually

Comment: @Maciej Stachowski Does my answer now correctly represent your comment?

Comment: @DavidSiegel Yes, thanks for including it :)

Comment: Do you think the "it" can be omitted in ""The water was too hot, so I drank [it] 10 minutes later" ?

Comment: @Apollyon  Yes I do, but omitting it would be somewhat unusual.

Comment: Likewise, many people find it odd to omit "it" in "The milk was so hot that I couldn't drink [it]," when the thing that was intended to be consumed was the milk.

Comment: But consider this:"The restaurant provided free mineral water, so she filled the glass and drank." This seems more acceptable than the above sentence, without "it."

Comment: @Apollyon I think that follows my "rule of thumb" the liquid is clearly indicated by context, and there is no plausible alternate meaning to avoid. I can actually imagine a context in which this sentence does **not** mean "drank mineral water" but it is a bit contrived and unlikely.

Comment: Do you agree the mineral water example is more natural than the hot milk example?, when "it" is omitted from both?

Comment: @Apollyon Yes, But I still think (a1) the hot milk example, is reasonably natural as it stands. And consider: "*The waiter put down a bottle of beer. She didn't need to conserve her drink, since the restaurant provided free mineral water, so she filled the glass and drank.*" a bit contrived, but not too odd.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence without "it" is also grammatically correct, but the meaning is not what you intend.

> The milk was so hot that I couldn't drink **it**.

This means "The milk was so hot that I was unable to drink the milk."

> The milk was so hot that I couldn't drink.

This means "The milk was so hot that I was unable to drink *anything*", or "... that I wasn't able to drink *alcohol*". It doesn't make a lot of sense. From the context, I might understand that you're talking about the milk, but if you are, that sense of "drink" must be transitive because you're drinking something specific, so it's a grammar error.

Comment: Does the following sound OK without an object following "drank"? "The restaurant provided free mineral water, so she filled the glass and drank."

Comment: @Apollyon Yes, that's correct and natural. We understand everything from the context.

Comment: But "The milk was so hot that I couldn't drink. I drank after 10 minutes" is also understandable from context, yet somehow the object "it" is still needed. There's something more than context to this issue.

Comment: @Apollyon If the intent is "I couldn't drink the milk", then the problem is pure grammar. It literally means, "I was unable to drink anything" or "I was unable to drink alcohol". There's no other meaning for intransitive "drink" in that context that I know of.

Comment: I suspect specificity plays a role in licensing the use of the intransitive "drink."